# android save Ringtone in Sharedpreferences and get it again

Tags: java, android, ringtone

I have get the current ringtone . Now I just want to save it in the `sharedpreference` .

How can I achieve that?

Here the code I tried:

```
Uri currentRintoneUri = 
          RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context.getApplicationContext(), 
                                                      RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
Ringtone currentRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, currentRintoneUri);
```

It's not working for ringing tone but it works for edit text :

```
sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPRE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String current = sharedpreferences.getString(CUR, "");
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString(CUR, String.valueOf((currentRingtone)));
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need.

Comment: i just want to save currentringtone in sharedprefrences and get it.

Comment: That's because you can only save primitive data types in SharedPrefs. Can you convert the `Uri` to string and save it that way? and then later recreate the `Uri` from string?

Comment: will you please give me ans with some code i am new in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy, your code was right. I just wrote a Demo test your code.

You maybe needed **Permission** `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` when called this code segment `Ringtone currentRingtone = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, currentRintoneUri);`

When I called the code segment I got this warning in logcat: `W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side; trying server side: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.media.MediaProvider uri content://media/external/audio/media/79645 from pid=8293, uid=11729 requires android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, or grantUriPermission()`

So, the right way is to save the `String.valueOf(Uri)` in SharedPreferences **NOT** save the `String.valueOf(Ringtone object)`.

Comment: i also have this permission

Comment: please tell me how to set it as a ringtone?

Comment: `RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);` In addition, the `newUri` must had existed in the MediaStore ContentProvider.

Comment: if we set the ringtone with this method what about the other ringtone which is already set?

Answer (score 0):

When you want to get Ringtone Same process,

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());

String ringtone = preferences.getString("CUR", "DEFAULT_SOUND");

Uri uri = Uri.parse(ringtone);
```

Now you can use uri to get ringtone.

Comment: i cant understand it will you please describe more?

Comment: i use uri to get ringtone but nothing get